# Friendship and Interfaces

Tags: c++

I'm having a compilation error using Apple's Clang 7.0 with the following friendship code, using C++11 standard. I wonder what's really wrong with it since it seems to be valid for me. I'm describing the setting and the error I'm having:

MyInterface

```
namespace namespace1
{

class MyInterface
{
friend class MyClass;
public:
    virtual void some_method(void) = 0;
    ...
private:
    type some_attribute;   
    ...
}

}
```

MyClass::MyMethod Implementation

```
namespace namespace2
{

void MyClass::MyMethod(MyInterface* MyConcrete)
{
    ...
    // MyConcrete implements MyInterface
    if(MyConcrete->some_attribute == some_value) // Error*
    {
       ...
    }
    ...
}

}
```

Error

```
error: 'some_attribute' is a private member of 'namespace1::MyInterface'
```

I really expected that `MyClass` would have access to `some_attribute` in `MyConcrete` (which implemented `MyInterface`) regardless of the class access modifier. Any clues why this error is happening? Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot compile your complete minimal example. It seems to be missing a main function.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz better check your compiler. It should have tripped over the misuse of `...` long before linking.

Comment: Friendship in an interface completely defies what interfaces are purposed for. Bad idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyClass is in `namespace2`. So you need to use:

```
friend class namespace2::MyClass;
```

You may also need to use forward decleration of `MyClass` before you define `MyInterface`.

Here's an example that compiles:

```
// forward decleration
namespace namespace2
{
    class MyClass;
}

namespace namespace1
{
    class MyInterface
    {
        friend class namespace2::MyClass; // added missing namespace
    public:
        virtual void some_method(void) = 0;

    private:
        int some_attribute;
    };
}


namespace namespace2
{
    class MyClass
    {
        void MyMethod(namespace1::MyInterface* MyConcrete)
        {
            if(MyConcrete->some_attribute == 1)
            {
            }
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
}
```

You can run it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nD6A6MnQB3Yrlv58).

Answer (score 1):

`friend class MyClass;` in the context of `::namespace1::MyInterface` refers to the class `::namespace1::MyClass`, which is a different class from `::namespace2::MyClass`.  (That's the whole point of namespaces, right?)

Change the friend declaration to read like this:

```
friend class ::namespace2::MyClass;
```

Note that this requires that the type `::namespace2::MyClass` has already been declared, so you either need to forward-declare it (`namespace namespace2 { class MyClass; }`) or you need to make sure that the definition is included prior to the definition of `::namespace1::MyInterface`.

(See [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2dffc3d8feb5185).)